Open URL Intent removes colons from URL Link
I am trying to implement a bluetooth printer functionality directly from browser.
The app has an intent option that can be used to print from browser "bprint://"
When I call the function window.open("bprint://" + "https://www.example.com",'_blank')
It actually tries to open bprint://https//www.example.com which then breaks the functionality because of the removed colon after https.
I also tried creating a link and set its href attribute, which has the same result.
Is there any way to open this URL intent maintaning the original url?
